# Is it possible to test a Vue 3 Composition library which uses inject without a wrapping component?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I'm following this guide to create an auth composition library: https://mattlaw.dev/blog/vuejs-the-composition-api-and-firebase-authentication/

At a high level, you define a file /src/components/auth/index.ts and that file has refs and "use" functions defined and directly exported, like:

```js
export const user = ref(null);

export function useSignup() {
  const email = ref("");
  const password = ref("");

  async function signup() {
    if (email.value == "" || password.value == "") return;

    const creds = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email.value,
      password.value
    );

    if (!creds.user) throw Error("Signup failed");

    user.value = creds.user;
  }

  return {
    email,
    password,
    signup,
  };
}
```

I want to replace the "auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword" with a fake injected auth service so I can purely test the useSignup function, but I don't want to have to initiate a full component to wrap this as part of my test. Is there a way to get a vue app context, "provide" a DI property, and then test this from jest so I'm purely testing the useSignup code?

Comment: My current thinking is to update the useSignup function to take an authService that it will call, but I can't help but feel there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to test `useSignup()` without any component context is to import the `auth` module in `useSignup()`:

```js
import { ref } from "vue";
import auth from "@/auth"; // 

export const user = ref(null);

export function useSignup() {
  const email = ref("");
  const password = ref("");

  async function signup() {
    if (email.value == "" || password.value == "") return;

    const creds = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email.value,
      password.value
    );

    if (!creds.user) throw Error("Signup failed");

    user.value = creds.user;

    return creds.user
  }

  return {
    email,
    password,
    signup,
  };
}
```

Then your test could mock that module:

1. Use `jest.mock('@/auth')` at the top of the test file.
2. In your test, `require` the module (which has been mocked above), and use `mockReturnValue()` to set the mock return value.
3. Setup the credentials `ref` values, and call `signup()`.
4. Verify the mock `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` was called.

```js
import { useSignup } from "@/useSignup";

jest.mock("@/auth"); 1️⃣

describe("useSignup", () => {
  it("signs in", async () => {
    2️⃣
    const { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require("@/auth").default;
    const myEmail = "john@gmail.com";
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword.mockReturnValue({
      user: myEmail
    });

    3️⃣
    const { email, password, signup } = useSignup();
    email.value = myEmail;
    password.value = "myPassword";
    await signup();

    4️⃣
    expect(createUserWithEmailAndPassword).toHaveBeenCalledWith(email.value, password.value);
  })
})
```